# minipage in tabular gives Underfull or Overfull \hbox

Tags: tables, minipage

I'm trying to put two tabulars together inside minipages inside a larger table.

For the reader it is convenient to have these two tables next to each other. The problem is that I get

> ```
> Overfull \hbox (12.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 498--533
> [][]
> ```

My `.tex` looks like this (as per recommendation of the conference I use `\CaptionType` which might be a macro that they supply in their `.sty` file)

```
\begin{table*}[t] 
  %\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l| r r r r}\hline\hline
           ...       
        \end{tabular}
        \CaptionType{table}
        \caption{...}
        \label{tab:res2}
     \end{minipage}
   \\
   \\
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{l| r r r r}\hline\hline
         ...
      \end{tabular}
      \CaptionType{table}
      \caption{...}
      \label{tab:res3}
   \end{minipage}
 \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

I get the same problem when I try to put two `\includegraphics` next to each other in another table (also using minipage). The document that comes out looks nice to me, but they are strict about warnings at the conference.

This is listed as the reason for the underfull problem:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \begin{tabular}{ c@{} c@{} }

    \noindent\par\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}%0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{1.eps} %%get Underfull here
      \CaptionType{figure}
      \caption{ ... }
      \label{fig:1}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \noindent\par\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}%0.5\textwidth}
      includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,clip=true,trim=0mm 5cm 0mm 0mm]{2.eps} %%get underfull here
      \CaptionType{figure}
      \caption{...}
      \label{fig:2}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

Errors:

```
[1] [2] <1.eps>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 247--251

<2.eps>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 257--260
```

Comment: Another typically reason for an overfull hbox is the par indention.  (`\par\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`) Put `\noindent` before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

### Code

```
\begin{table*}[t] 
  %\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} %                                this line changed!
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l| r r r r}\hline\hline
           ...       
        \end{tabular}
        \CaptionType{table}
        \caption{...}
        \label{tab:res2}
     \end{minipage}
   \\
   \\
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{l| r r r r}\hline\hline
         ...
      \end{tabular}
      \CaptionType{table}
      \caption{...}
      \label{tab:res3}
   \end{minipage}
 \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

### Explanation

LaTeX `tabular`s put small horizontal spaces (`\tabcolsep`) before/between/after columns. With `@{}` you can override this space, in this case with nothing (= no space).